What is this experimental design called?
Suppose I gather data from an experiment with 2 treatments: a_1 and a_2. There are 3 blocks b_1 through b_3.
Each subject experiences only one treatment (either a_1 or a_2, not both).
Each block experiences both treatments.
Each combination (subject, block, treatment) results in a continuous (time) observation.



Subject
Block
Treatment a_1
Treatment a_2




1
b_1
Value



1
b_2
Value



1
b_3
Value



2
b_1

Value


2
b_2

Value


2
b_3

Value



This table continues until all subjects (people) are covered.
I know this isn't RCBD because not all treatments are applied each time.
What is the name of this experimental design? I need to find a formula to help with sample size calculation (no data have been gathered yet, this is just in the brainstorming phase).

In analysis of variance (ANOVA) speak, this is referred to as a mixed factorial ANOVA, which can be used to test between-subjects differences (here, treatment) as well within-subjects (i.e., repeated measures) differences (here, block).
In your case with two factors, of which one has two levels (treatment) and one has three levels (block), one could refer to this as a 2x3 mixed design.

Doesn't 2x2 mixed design refer to 2 treatments and 2 blocks? Here I have 3 blocks.

@StatsSorceress, yes, you are correct. I edited my answer accordingly.
